# Can we use google sign-in for Gmail APIs?

Tags: android, ios, gmail-api, google-signin

In our App we have Google sign-in integrated as explained here :

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Our App is also looking for users Gmail account using serverAuthCode provided by Gmail. So can we use Google sign-in for Gmail API access or we need to have Gmail sign in as explained here :

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Authorizing Your App with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth):

> All requests to the Gmail API must be authorized by an authenticated
>   user. Gmail uses the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authenticating a Google
>   account and authorizing access to user data. You can also use Google+
>   Sign-in to provide a "sign-in with Google" authentication method for
>   your app.

If you watch the video from the Google Sign-in link you provided, you will know that this tool is used to handle "signing-in". Now if you want to use Gmail APIs, you'll have to do more. Aside from OAuth, you will need to handle  [authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/#auth_and_the_gmail_api), as well as scopes.

Since you seem to be working on Android and iOS, check this quickstarts. They have sign-in for Gmail API implemented:

[Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android)

[iOS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios)

Comment: Thank you, We are going to have gmail sign-in, specific to ios & anrdoid. Same as in your links provided for ios & android.

Comment: There is nothing in that quickstart guide about GMAIL API